# Textarea line breaks

Tags: php, html, css

I'm storing description data from textrea field to database. The problem is when i write a long line text without line breaks it's storing the same to database. I need to prevent line breaks depends on textarea width...
[image: example]

and output is going out from container...
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it's that the output breaks the div you're putting it in - that makes it a CSS issue, not a PHP one.

You can use the `word-wrap: break-word;` CSS attribute, which will break the words if they exceed the width of the container.

```css
.break {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 100px;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="break">
      Thisisaverylongstringexceedingthewidthofthecontainer
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks))